# aws emr with yarn scheduler

Tags: hadoop-yarn, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

I am creating AWS EMR using cloudformation template. I need to run the steps parallel. For that I am trying to change the YARN Scheduler from FIFO to fair / capacity scheduler.

I have added:

```
yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class : 'org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler'
```

Do I need to add `FairScheduler.xml` file in conf.empty folder?  If so, can you please share the xml file.
and if I want to add `fairscheduler.xml` through cloudformation template, then do I need to use bootstrap for it? if so could you provide me the bootstrap file please.

Comment: How are you sending your jobs to EMR? If you use emr-steps they always run sequentially (not in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like even though after changing the scheduler, EMR won't allow to run jobs concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your cluster by specifying the configuration in cloud-formation scripts.

This a example to configure

```
    - Classification: fair-scheduler
      ConfigurationProperties:
        <key1>: <value1>
        <key2>: <value2>
    - Classification: yarn-site
      ConfigurationProperties:
        yarn.acl.enable: true
        yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler
```

Please follow these -

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticmapreduce-cluster-configuration.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html

EMR recently allows you to run multiple steps in parallel -

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-emr-now-allows-you-to-run-multiple-steps-in-parallel-cancel-running-steps-and-integrate-with-aws-step-functions/